# $.getJSON not returning a response with MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I spent a LONG time looking into this and just can't see what's wrong. I have the following:

```
$.getJSON(
                '/adminStatus/GetJsonData',
                { name: $('#textSearch')[0].value },
                function (data) {
                    alert("3");
//                  $('#studentList > div').remove();
//                  for (s in data) {
//                      alert("4");
//                      var student = data[s];
//                      $('#studentList').append('<div>(' + student.StudentId + ') ' + student.FirstName + ' ' + student.LastName + '</div>');
//                  }
                }
            );
```

This code fires an action in my controller and that action returns data. It's actually code from another example:

```
public JsonResult GetJsonData(string name)
        {
            return new JsonResult
            {
                Data = (from student in Student.GetStudentDataList()
                        where student.LastName.StartsWith(name)
                        select student).ToArray<Student>()
            };
        }
```

I check and Data is getting populated with data.

However nothing is happening with return data and when I added comments then I cannot even get the alert("3") to appear.

Am I doing something really obviously wrong? I think I'm copying a working example but nothing seems to be returned and the function (data) {} does not seem to execute.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you have any JavaScript errors on the page? Have you run your code through http://jslint.com to check for errors?

Answer (score 11):

It would be best to check this in something like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) to see if there are any errors occurring.  Trying to troubleshoot without knowing exactly what's going on is just going to lead to more frustration.

One thing I see being a potential problem is that you don't have `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` set, so you might be getting a server error. To see if that's the case you can change your return to read:

```
var data = (from student in Student.GetStudentDataList()
           where student.LastName.StartsWith(name)
           select student).ToArray<Student>();

return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Comment: Yeah - not having JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet with MVC3 is going to be an issue

Answer (score 1):

When debugging this kind of problem , [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) is the best tool since it's always showing you what's under the hood.